# iterate keys and values of embedded dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, loops, key-value

I have written the following code to compute the sum of the values in each embedded dictionary and for each embedded dictionary I would also like to retain the keys that correspond to those values.  As you can see below, for example, I would like to know that 20+30+40 = 90 but I would also like to retain the keys:loan1, loan2, loan3 and know that their values are 20,30,40 respectively so that I can create a new dictionary.

I have done this writing three for loops and I think it can be done more concisely.  Also, I have run this a few times and while the for loop that prints the values of the embedded dictionaries, and the for loop that records the keys of the embedded dictionaries iterate in the same order each time, I am not sure that what I have written ensures that.

```
mydict = {'k1':{'loan1':20,'loan2':30, 'loan3':40},'k2':{'loan1':90,'loan2':65, 'loan3':75}}

for k in mydict.keys():

    the_sum = 0

    for c in mydict[k].itervalues():
        the_sum += c

        print k, c, the_sum

    for k2 in mydict[k].iterkeys():
        print k2

k2 75 75

k2 65 140

k2 90 230
loan3

loan2

loan1

k1 40 40

k1 30 70

k1 20 90

loan3

loan2

loan1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want it to print the sum? Or do you want to add the sum as a new field in the dictionary? If you just want the sum for a given key, you can do:

```
In [1]: mydict = {'k1':{'loan1':20,'loan2':30, 'loan3':40},'k2':{'loan1':90,'loan2':65, 'loan3':75}}

In [2]: for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
   ...:     print k, sum(v.values())
   ...:
   ...:
k2 230
k1 90
```

And retain all of your original information. If you want to add a `total` to each field, you can do:

```
In [3]: for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
   ...:     v['total'] = sum(v.values())
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: mydict
Out[4]:
{'k1': {'loan1': 20, 'loan2': 30, 'loan3': 40, 'total': 90},
 'k2': {'loan1': 90, 'loan2': 65, 'loan3': 75, 'total': 230}}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted @RocketDonkey but you gave me the clue I needed.  Thanks

Comment: @user1816858 No worries, happy it helped :) For our collective edification, what was the exact output you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to sum the value of the loans for each key, you could use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) like this:

```
mydict = {'k1':{'loan1':20,'loan2':30, 'loan3':40},
          'k2':{'loan1':90,'loan2':65, 'loan3':75}}

totals = {key:sum(loans.values()) for key, loans in mydict.items()}
print(totals)
```

yields

```
{'k2': 230, 'k1': 90}
```

If you are using Python2.6 or older, then you could form the dict, `totals` using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
totals = dict((key,sum(loans.values())) for key, loans in mydict.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely. As for getting the sum of your dictionary, you can replace your for loop with a list comprehension and sum()

```
>>> mydict = {'k1':{'loan1':20,'loan2':30, 'loan3':40},'k2':{'loan1':90,'loan2':65, 'loan3':75}}
>>> sum([x for x in mydict['k1'].itervalues()])
90
>>> sum([x for x in mydict['k2'].itervalues()])
230
```

This does leave mydict unmodified, so your key/values are retained. Also python dictionaries are **unordered**, if you want the keys to be retained in order look into python's collections.ordereddict